# Why is the opacity of the background color of the HTML hr tag decreasing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to change the height and background color of the `<hr>` tag in HTML. Although the height and color change, but it seems the background color opacity is reducing slightly. Why is this happening?

My Code:

```html
<hr class="mb-4" style="width: 10%; margin: auto; height: 10px; border: none; color:#f24516; background-color:#f24516;">
```

How can I get the original color and why is this problem happening? I am using the current version of Chrome (Windows 10).

**Edited**

I get such output in the browser when I run the whole code:
[image]

My whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="./images/favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    header {
      background: url(./images/bg-masthead.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .navbar-brand {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    #header-texts-1 {
      font-size: 50px;
    }
    
    #header-texts-2 {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    
    #header-btn {
      background: #f24516;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 20px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    }
    /* ========================= Responsive ========================= */
    
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .navbar-expand-lg {
        background: transparent !important;
      }
      a {
        color: white !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <title>Creative</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light menu" id="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav" id="nav-items">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Protfolio</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center py-5" id="header-texts">
        <div class="col">
          <p id="header-texts-1">YOUR FAVORITE SOURCE OF FREE<br>BOOTSTRAP THEMES</p>
          <hr class="mb-4" style="width: 10%; margin: auto; height: 10px; border: none; color:#f24516; background-color:#f24516;">
          <p id="header-texts-2">Start Bootstrap can help you build better websites using the Bootstrap<br>framework! Just download a theme and start customizing, no strings attached!</p>
          <button class="btn mt-4" id="header-btn">FIND OUT MORE</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
  <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
  <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
  <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
  <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
  <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
  <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by blurring? In the example you provided i dont think i see blurring? Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: I am on W10 and latest version of chrome, the line seems to be correct, here a screenshot: https://ibb.co/C1p01YY

Comment: @ItsFragilis I mean it seems the opacity is decreased.

Comment: Try a sharper color, a pure red: `#ff0000`. Then create the same color in a color palette to compare it. The color of your example is correct.

Comment: I am on macOS and latest version of chrome, the color seems okay to me, i think you should try @Baro suggestion

Comment: I have added full code now. Please check it

Comment: Here I just gave the code of the <hr> tag. If I run the code here, I can see the correct color in my browser, but when I run the whole code, the color becomes a little lighter.

Running whole code seems in browser: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11tXi_m5ZOpk6WLco_Fq_v4aq4h71XouK/view?usp=sharing

Running here seems:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12v3NlFLm9Gpsp0OJNa8Q-OC1DLp1PMuG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a reboot.css  in bootstrap file that has `opacity: .25`, so you have to reset your `hr` by adding `opacity: 1` to it

Answer (score 2):

In your `reboot.scss` you have an `hr` style with `opacity:.25;`.

Add:

```
        hr {
          opacity:1;
        }
```

```html
<hr class="mb-4" style="width: 10%; margin: auto; height: 10px; border: none; color:#f24516; background-color:#ff0000;">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
            list-style: none;
        }
        header {
            /*background: url(./images/bg-masthead.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;*/
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .navbar-brand {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        #header-texts-1 {
            font-size: 50px;
        }
        #header-texts-2 {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #header-btn {
            background: #f24516;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 20px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            letter-spacing: 0.8px;
        }
        hr {
          opacity:1;
        }
        /* ========================= Responsive ========================= */
        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .navbar-expand-lg {
                background: transparent !important;
            }
            a {
                color: white !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <title>Creative</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light menu" id="navigation">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                                <div class="navbar-nav" id="nav-items">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Protfolio</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center py-5" id="header-texts">
                <div class="col">
                    <p id="header-texts-1">YOUR FAVORITE SOURCE OF FREE<br>BOOTSTRAP THEMES</p>
                    <hr class="mb-4" style="width: 10%; margin: auto; height: 10px; border: none; color:#f24516; background-color:#f24516;">
                    <p id="header-texts-2">Start Bootstrap can help you build better websites using the Bootstrap<br>framework! Just download a theme and start customizing, no strings attached!</p>
                    <button class="btn mt-4" id="header-btn">FIND OUT MORE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```